# Double mouse pointer in ZoomIt

Tags: windows-7

SysInternals ZoomIt allows you to annotate on your screen during a presentation. It also allows you to use the LiveZoom feature, so you can zoom into an area to make small text readable in the back of the room. I also use Zoomit when I record with e.g. CamStudio.

When I use the LiveZoom feature my screen shows two mouse cursors. Depending on the position, they can be overlapping or up to two inches apart. I have played with the mouse settings to no avail.

How can I solve this?

One more thing, which I have NOT been able to solve: Both Chrome and ZoomIt use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys. How do I zoom in/out further, beyond the set default? I know the obvious answer, which is to use IE, but I would like to avoid that...

Answer (score 1):

SysInternals ZoomIt ONLY works properly (i.e. not showing a double mouse pointer) when `Aero Glass` is enabled. So I made a shortcut to `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows` by searching for it in the Start menu search and selecting `create shortcut`. It can also be found in the `Control Panel` under `Performance Information and Tools`.

Here I can switch between the simple and faster XP style which I like (and with a reliably working <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) or switch all the bells and whistles "on" before a presentation or recording (and remember to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> instead)...